# Joomla secondary language code in the Url causes js files not to be found

Tags: joomla, adobe-edge

Adobe Edge Animate's index_edgePreload.js file has the following:

```
aLoader = [
      { load: "templates/mst/edge_includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"},
      { load: "templates/mst/edge_includes/edge.4.0.1.min.js"},
      { load: "templates/mst/index_edge.js"},
      { load: "templates/mst/index_edgeActions.js"}];
```

When I have the secondary language in Joomla, paths cannot be found, and the animation cannot be displayed. Works fine with ab.com or abc.com/en but when it comes to abc.com/tr: 404. Been googling all day.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your code to:

```
aLoader = [
      { load: "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/mst/edge_includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"},
      { load: "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/mst/edge_includes/edge.4.0.1.min.js"},
      { load: "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/mst/index_edge.js"},
      { load: "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/mst/index_edgeActions.js"}];
```

That would be better to use joomla [native js addition method](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript).
Your result would be:

```
<?php
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScript('/templates/mst/edge_includes/jquery-2.0.3.min.js');
  $document->addScript('/templates/mst/edge_includes/edge.4.0.1.min.js');
  $document->addScript('/templates/mst/index_edge.js');
  $document->addScript('/templates/mst/index_edgeActions.js');
?>
```

Good Luck!